Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null
i just installed the @solana/web3.js package and getting this error:
Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null TypeError: Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null     at ./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95779:34)     at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:623205:31)     at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:622599:32)     at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:622863:21)     at ./src/pages/cryptobasket/Test.jsx (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48762:73)     at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:623205:31)     at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:622599:32)     at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:622863:21)     at ./src/component/common/RouterComponent.jsx (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12857:82)     at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:623205:31) 

I tryied to downgrade the @solana/web3.js to ^1.36.0, and still no luck.
react version: "^18.3.1"
node version: v18.20.2

I had same error.
Try this:
npm uninstall --save @solana/web3.js

and then:
npm install --save @solana/web3.js@^1.90.0

if you get a dependency error during installation, run this:
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @solana/web3.js@^1.90.0

With 1.90.0 solana/web3.js version my project works.
